# Testing ngrx store: No provider for MockStore

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am following the Official Documentation for Testing ngrx Stores: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing

Even the simplest implementation of injecting a MockStore has the following Error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[MockStore -> MockStore]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for MockStore!
    error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'MockStore', 'MockStore' ] })
```

My code looks like this:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideMockStore, MockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

describe('Auth Guard', () => {
  // @ts-ignore
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // any modules needed
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore(),
        // other providers
      ],
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(store).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am Running @ngrx/store@8.6.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***UPDATED***

based on discussion `store = TestBed.inject(Store);` instead of `MockStore` is enough for the desired behavior.

***ORIGINAL***

It is too early,

get it in the test:

```js
  it('should create', inject([Store], (store) => {
    expect(store).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

not sure, but you can try to call compileComponents.

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // any modules needed
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore(),
        // other providers
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });
```

Comment: Your first solution gets the test running, but not beacause it is to early, but because it Injects a Store instead of a MockStore. So simply `store = TestBed.inject(Store);` fixes it and injects a mock store. Will you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: ah, sure! nice!